# Does the prestige of a gym automatically degrade over time?

Tags: pokemon-go

5 days ago I became a member of a level 10 gym which had `52,000` prestige. The prestige remained at `52,000` until 2 days ago when it fell to *exactly* `50,000` (still 10 pokemon. ok). Last night, the prestige fell to *exactly* `49,500` (now with 9 pokemon. ok).

That each degradation happened in units of `500` surely means pokemon are getting kicked-out, but why? Is it the passage of time that is kicking out pokemon automatically?

**note (1)**:
During the 5 minutes it took to write this, gym prestige fell to *exactly* `49,000`, **BUT** there are still 9 pokemon! What the heck? How did the gym lose `500` but not lose a pokemon?

**note (final)**:
20-min has just passed, and now I see fighting at the gym. My gym mates are counter-attacking and have pushed prestige back up to `48,978`. So, the "attack" was in units of `500` and the counter-attack was in units of `1`. In essence, that is my question.

Comment: Pokemon are only kicked out when the gym level decreases. So after dropping below 50k when the gym dropped from lvl 10 to lvl 9 one Pokemon got kicked.

Comment: @dly I just thought prestige decreased by 500 + a variable amount based on the CP of the fighters. Clearly I was wrong.

Comment: Yep. The answer already states how it works. 500 per Pokemon defeated + 1000(?) bonus for defeating all Pokemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Training works with variable xp.

Fighting gyms always costs a multiple of 500 prestige. I've seen up to 2500 prestige reductions. This is based on the amount of pokemon you beat and if the attacker won the entire battle series.

Beating a single pokemon and having all your pokemon faint vs the second one results in 500 prestige reduction.

Comment: I thought defeating a pokemon reduced prestige by (500 + x). Training definitely increases prestige by a variable based on the CP of the fighters.  Defeating a pokemon is straight-up 500? I just never noticed. thanks!

Comment: Small addition to your answer: The maximum prestige attainable by training at a gym is 50,000, and any training done at that gym which would place it above that value will instead set it to that value exactly. However, a gym also gains 2,000 prestige upon the placement of a new defender, which means a fully-stocked level 10 gym will get bounced up to 52,000. Any further fights there (including friendly training!) will force another max-value check and bump it back to 50k, which may also have been why OP saw it at that value.